# lasso - how to evaluate results

Tags: r, cross-validation, lasso, lars

I'm working on lasso as an alternative to step-wise forward/backward regression using the `lars` package in R. I normalized my variables, calculated the `lars` and did a CV for figuring out the most suitable fraction s. After that I used that s-value for predicting my model using `predict.lars` and identify those variables to use and to neglect in my regression equation.
No I got stucked in the further evaluation of my work. What needs to be done next to evaluate the fitting of my model. Is there a kind of p-value and R-square to use as parameter for valuation?
I would like to use the regression equation for interpolation my Y using the variables to a map and need to evaluate the regression.

I know that there are many topics covering my question at a certain point but after browsing the website and literature (Elements of Statistical Learning, An introduction to statistical learning, regression shrinkage and selection via lasso, a significance test for the lasso) I came not up with a specific result.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the predicted values from lars and from stepwise on the test data and see how close each comes to the actual values.

However, a lot of this sort of thing has been done already so, unless this project is for your own education, you should review the literature on how well lars works.  One source is *Regression Modelling Strategies* by Frank Harrell (get the 2nd edition, published this year) that has a lot of material and an extensive bibliography.

Also take a look at the [Lasso Page](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/lasso.html) which has a lot of material.

Comment: Comparing of predicted values is a good idea. Thanks you for that unknown resources. But is there a way to obtain R²?

Comment: You can re-run the model that lars suggests in lm and get whatever you like

Comment: Thank you. How should I consider "intercept"? In lasso, the intercept = T and therefore  0 but it's not the case in lm and therefore the coefficients are different.

Comment: If you re-run the model in lm then the intercept will not be 0.